# How to access members of a `struct' according to a value of a string?

Tags: c, string, struct

I would like to access a member within a struct by using the value of a string:

```
struct hello_world
{
           char rate;
           char ssid;
};
```

There is a varibale let's say

```
char *string="ssid";
```

I would like to use the value of this string to refer to the `ssid` member within the `hello_world` struct. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

Nope, it's not.

You need a (long) `if-else` statement, that will do this. Like:

```
struct hello_world hw;
char *string="ssid";

if( 0 == strcmp( "ssid", string ) )
{
     // use hw.ssid
}
else if ...
```

Comment: This feature is called reflection, which C does not have.

Comment: @tjameson - true. Good note.

Comment: BTW, you don't need that constant-first-comparison safety check in this particular case since `strcmp ("ssid", string) = 0` (accidentally using assignment instead of comparison) won't compile.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a string, you are better off using an enum with all the possible cases.

```
typedef enum {
    FIELD_SSID,
    FIELD_RATE,
} field_t

field_t string;
```

and then use a switch

```
switch (string) {
    case FIELD_SSID:
        //use ssid
        break;
    case FIELD_RATE:
        //use rate
        break;
}
```

This method is way faster than comparing strings.

If you only use one field **OR** the other, you could use a union instead of a struct.

Comment: Yep, I thought about this one, but gave up suggesting it because the title asks if this is possible, using strings. +1 anyway :)

Comment: well with strings you'd need an hash function, and then do the switch on the result of the hash, but you'd need to hardcode those results or to use a macro i suppose.

Answer (score -1):

Define a function, like a wrapper to pass the member back you want.

```
char GiveMember(struct hello_world, char* member){ }
```

But the language itself does not provide you with anything like this.

Comment: What if the members are different type?

Comment: after `void*` is returned, the caller needs to know the type, again (to cast it back to the correct type). Sounds to me like a job, done twice. Don't get me wrong - I like the idea, but it will not always work:)

Comment: @KirilKirov I agree, but if you want to push it and force a mechanism like this... ;)